# Check if image is homogeneous

Tags: c++, opencv

How can a check whether an image is homogeneous can be done?

For example this is an homogeneous image:

[image]

And this is not (because of the white dot):

[image]

Comment: If a color is dithered is the image homogeneous?

Answer (score 2):

I have three ideas, but first you should convert the image to grey-scale:

1. Edge-filtering: if the image is homogeneous, there will be no edges. So you can sum the pixel in the filtered image and adjust a threshold to determine if the image is smooth or not.
2. binarization: you could  determine the mean pixelvalue and use this as threshold for binarization, all the brighter pixel will remain
3. fourier transformation: a fourier transformed homogeneous image has only very low frequencies

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I'm a beginner in opencv, could you please write one of the methods suggested?

Comment: I'm not familiar with opencv, but there a lot of examples you can use: [Edgefiltering](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/doc/tutorials/imgproc/imgtrans/sobel_derivatives/sobel_derivatives.html) ; [Binarization](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/doc/tutorials/imgproc/threshold/threshold.html) ; [Fourier transformation](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/doc/tutorials/core/discrete_fourier_transform/discrete_fourier_transform.html)